# Godot GDScript code for jumping not working

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm making a 2d left-to-right style game (In the same vain as games like hollow night, so you get a gist of the controls) and I have the following code inside the main player's kinematic body. The jump ("up") part of this code doesn't work. Pressing up appears to do nothing, although "Worked" is printed. The gravity portion (`velocity.y += 1000`) does. I have tried putting it into a while loop, however in that not even the printing worked.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export (int) var speed = 200

var velocity = Vector2()

func get_input():
    velocity = Vector2()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("up"):
        #this bit doesnt work.
        velocity.y -= 1000
        #this is printed though
        print("Worked")
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed

func _physics_process(delta):
    get_input()
    velocity.y += 1000
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Comment: I have removed the python tag. This is not python. Whoever is recommending people to add the python tag as an attempt to have more people see the question, please stop already.

Comment: @Theraot apologies, I added it because gdscript is based on python, and therefore it seemed somewhat likely someone might know.

Answer (score 0):

Let met take something out of the way: `velocity.y += 1000` is frame rate dependent. In effect, it is an acceleration of a thousand pixels per second per frame. You probably want to do something like this: `velocity.y += gravity * delta`. Where `gravity` is acceleration in pixels per second squared.

Similarly, these are accelerations: `velocity.x += 1`, `velocity.x -= 1`. They are increasing and decreasing horizontal velocity by one pixel per second per frame. However, your are normalizing the velocity and scaling by `speed`. Are you able to decelerate and change directions?

---

About the problem, what I see is this:

First, you erase velocity (which also means that any downwards acceleration is gone):

```
velocity = Vector2()
```

Then, if the player just pressed `"up"`, this line runs:

```
velocity.y -= 1000
```

Which will result `velocity.y` having the value `-1000` (because it was erased to zero just before).

Then it gets normalized:

```
velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
```

If we assume no horizontal speed, now `velocity.y` is `-speed` (by default).

And later the same frame this line runs:

```
velocity.y += 1000
```

That will result in `velocity.y` having the value of `1000 - speed`. The sign depends on whatever or not `speed` is greater than `1000`.

Assuming it isn't (since it isn't by default), you are just getting a velocity in the direction of gravity regardless of the player pressing `"up"`.

---

To fix that we need to:

- Apply gravity when NOT jumping.
- Override the vertical velocity ONLY when jumping.

In fact, I would do something similar for the horizontal motion.

```
export var speed := 200.0
export var jump_speed := -1000.0

export var gravity := 1000.0


var velocity := Vector2.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta) -> void:
    velocity.x = Input.get_axis("left", "right") * speed
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("up"):
        velocity.y = jump_speed
    else:
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

I have got rid of `get_input`, because it was more something like `compute_velocity`, but we are messing with velocity in `_physics_process` for the gravity anyway. In fact, we need `delta` to do that correctly.

Of course that is no horizontal acceleration. Do you want horizontal acceleration? So that would make the `speed` into maximum `speed`, right? OK:

```
export var speed := 200.0
export var jump_speed := -1000.0
export var acceleration := 100.0

export var gravity := 1000.0


var velocity := Vector2.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta) -> void:
    var inpux_x := Input.get_axis("left", "right")
    velocity.x = clamp(
        velocity.x + input_x * acceleration * delta,
        -speed,
        speed
    )
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("up"):
        velocity.y = jump_speed
    else:
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

By the way, no, there is nothing wrong with taking input in `_physics_process`. In fact, this is intended.

---

*I also notice there are no ground checks on your code. I'll not dwell on that since that isn't the question.*

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for the python thing again and thanks for the help, I’m new to gdscript so thanks for that, also for the reminder for a ground check.